# SQL Server [Slow locally - Fast remotely]

Tags: sql-server

I have a strange (and interesting) problem, I just came with a company to support it with the ERP, every time the ERP client runs, it connects to a SQL server and creates a lot of views.

Well, if they run the ERP client on any computer on the network, the queries are pretty quick, but if you run the client on the sql server locally, then it takes up to 20 times the time it takes to run them from the remote computer.

I trace some queries from the ERP, executed them locally and also were executed very fast.

In summary, only when the client is used locally, queries are very slow.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you be running ERP client on SQL Server host?

Comment: SQL Server may be taking all the memory on the host, leaving very little for a client on the same machine. There are many other reasons why it could be slow locally and fast remotely.

Comment: Any chance you could share one of the queries?

Comment: I'm with @JamesZ here. Running a client application directly on the sql server seems like a very bad idea.

Comment: Ok, I'm agree it is a bad idea, however, when the connection it is unstable, then the employees use a Remote Desktop and executes the client locally, I know it's odd and dangerous, but that the way they use, now I've to reeducate them. I just wondering about the reason and I think that you guys give some ideas, thanks.